# "PulseTile-RA" cannot run. Is it an npm dependency issue?

Tags: npm, npm-install, react-admin, react-scripts

I wanted to experiment with this project based on react-admin:
https://github.com/PulseTile/PulseTile-RA

So I downloaded the code, run `npm install` and I got a lot of errors from NPM mainly `axios` version corrupted.

Example:

```sh
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-MtU+SFHv3AoRmTts0AB4nXDAUQI= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-MtU+SFHv3AoRmTts0AB4nXDAUQI= but got sha512-0BfJq4NSfQXd+SkFdrvFbG7addhYSBA2mQwISr46pD6E5iqkWg02RAs8vyTT/j0RTnoYmeXauBuSv1qKwR179g== sha1-/z8N4ue10YDnV62YAA8Qgbh7zqM=. (75833 bytes)
npm WARN tarball tarball data for js-yaml@3.13.1 (sha512-pZZoSxcCYco+DIKBTimr67J6Hy+EYGZDY/HCWC+iAEA9h1ByhMXAIVUXMcMFpOCxQ/xjXmPI2MkDL5HRm5eFrQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-pZZoSxcCYco+DIKBTimr67J6Hy+EYGZDY/HCWC+iAEA9h1ByhMXAIVUXMcMFpOCxQ/xjXmPI2MkDL5HRm5eFrQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-pZZoSxcCYco+DIKBTimr67J6Hy+EYGZDY/HCWC+iAEA9h1ByhMXAIVUXMcMFpOCxQ/xjXmPI2MkDL5HRm5eFrQ== but got sha512-YfbcO7jXDdyj0DGxYVSlSeQNHbD7XPWvrVWeVUujrQEoZzWJIRrCPoyk6kL6IAjAG2IolMK4T0hNUe0HOUs5Jw==. (74050 bytes)
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\xxx\PulseTile-RA\node_modules\.staging\babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread-7e34a6f0\package.json'*
```

When I do `npm start` I get an error that `react-scripts` doesn't exist.
I tried workarounds for similar errors on stackoverflow but without success. And yet still, I cannot get it to run. I have latest NPM, node on windows 10.

Please advise on NPM issues as I think this is the source of this project issue of not starting.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So technically, this has more to do with `npm` than the actual project.
In fact, [this issue reported to the npm repository would help](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861).

But here are some quick steps that should help:
Since you're in `windows-10`, it's advisable to run the "delete" commands within `git` bash.

- Go to the project directory (root folder)
- Delete the `node_modules` directory: `rm -rf node_modules`
- Delete `package-lock.json file:`rm package-lock.json`
- Clear the cache: npm cache clean --force
- Run `npm install --verbose`

If it doesn't help, then [please follow more instructions here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade/issues/113)

Comment: But now the landing pages gets stuck loading the login page, please advise.
I think it expects some database where users are stored but could not locate instructions.

Thank you.

Comment: There must be an error/warning logged in the console if the app is not acting right. Kindly share any errors, thanks.

Comment: I see a couple of warnings in console but nothing related to application failing to connect to a database and I could not see how to attached output of console to this thread using stackoverflow.

Comment: You could just add it to the question, with a note.